# How to totally disable cache in Wordpress?

Tags: cache

I have a plugin that somehow seems to be caching even though I have disabled cache in Firefox per these instructions:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232148

I have also tried browsing in Private Window (like Chrome incognito).

In wp-config I have

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
```

In the plugin's config file I have

```
if ( ! defined( 'LEARNDASH_TRANSIENTS_DISABLED' ) ) {
    define( 'LEARNDASH_TRANSIENTS_DISABLED', true );
}
```

No matter what I do, I notice it takes a couple minutes for edits in .php files to actually result in a change to the rendered broswer content.

Read that with wordpress server side cacheing can be quite tricky to fully disable.

Here is what I did as sanity check:

I edited a php file and included an echo statement with the word `whattheheck`. I refreshed the page, saw the text `wqhattheheck` then removed that echo statement and refreshed again and the page still displays `whattheheck` for *several minutes* after which point a refresh does not show the text.

I tried this after removing the echo statement:

```
grep -rwl “whattheheck” /var/www/mysite
```

which returned nothing. I also did a database dump and used

```
grep -n '/path/wordpress.sql' -e 'whattheheck'
```

which returned nothing. This is happening in all browsers, even say, Safari, where the first time I open the page in question it displays the text `whattheheck`. So there is absolutely no browser cache going on.

So, what we have here is a genuine mystery that begs the question:

**If no text file within the site root contains the text that I previously added to a php file, and the wp_options table doesn't contain the text (nor any other table), then how on earth is it that the page keeps showing this text for about 3 minutes after I remove the echo statement that produces the text?**

Really curious. It is almost as if wordpress (or plugin) reads a file into memory and uses the memory stored version of the file for some time, which could explain what I am seeing. That is, I edit a file (in my case in PHPStorm), upload it, and wordpress or plugin uses previously loaded version of the file. But I have never read that this happens in wordpress.

thanks,

Brian

Comment: Is opcache and php file cache active on the server?

Comment: Here is what I see: opcache.file_cache no value no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks 1 1
opcache.file_cache_only 0 0
opcache.file_update_protection 2 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout 180 180       So I guess this must be what is happening and the 180 corresponds to the 3 minutes I am noticing before changes take effect. The things is, on a Laravel site of mine I don't see this effect as I see changes immediately. So curious is there somewhere in wordpress where certain opcache settings are implemented?

Comment: WordPress has no settings for opcahce.